# chromium webapp does not load webview tag

Tags: web-applications, webview, chromium

I use chrome in an environment where all the webapps are trusted.
The webapp content must be loaded from localhost.

I have on the disk following manifest.json:

```
{
   "app": {
      "background": {
         "scripts": [ "main.js" ]
      }
   },
   "key": "MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQC1pfODEBUGdWWSnyl+T04CSxMnr/s8QKdpkCoqxpnUVoalo/0lp6/N/RfglcfjLSfpQbprjxZuV8YdKw2NmXfXMfTEDp2Mu1hTotroZy9yi6l7bNc2DLkYkzfJ26A+yRmKtY1hgT3UWLhsLyFEvbtdJo4rhTApqTnUbn6C/WyCGwIDAQAB",
   "manifest_version": 2,
   "permissions": [ "webview"],
   "version": "0.1"
}
```

main.js just create an app window, having localhost url as input:

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
  chrome.app.window.create('http://localhost/somewebapp', {
    id: 'embedder',
    bounds: {
      width: 1430,
      height: 870
    }
  });
})
```

I modified in the AppWindowCreateFunction::RunAsync to work also with non-local urls:

```
  GURL absolute = GURL(params->url);
  if (absolute.has_scheme()) {
    //if (extension()->location() == Manifest::COMPONENT) {
    if(true){
      url = absolute;
    } else {
      // Show error when url passed isn't local.
      error_ = app_window_constants::kInvalidUrlParameter;
      return false;
    }
  }
```

The page from localhost url contains webview tag:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
Web app
    <webview id="wv1" style="width:250px; height:200px;" src="http://localhost/page.html"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Observed behaviour:

- app window created and localhost page is loaded ("web app" text
  dsiplayed).
- WebView is not created and webview feature is not visible    in web
  inspector.

I would expect the webview to be created.
Does anyone have any idea why it works so and what chromium sources are responsible to load resources required in manifest (in our case webview)?

I would appreciate any help/suggestions. Thanks!